# Android: change app name in home screen

Tags: android

My app displays the name of its starting activity on the Home screen.  I've tried to change the name by setting the `android:label` attribute in the manifest, under `<application>` to no avail.  What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the name of the launcher activity using android:label. Seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: That would change the title in the Toolbar.  Not a desirable solution.

Answer (score 9):

Any activity with an intent filter for android.intent.category.Launcher will show up in the app drawer. You have to set a label for the activity as well as the application, the label for the activity (**android:label="@string/title_activity_main"**) is what will show up in the app drawer.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you change the name in your manifest, so it represents what you would like it to read.

In your manifest, use the element where you define your Activity, to have the following:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="whatever you want"/>
```

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about the starting activity?

Comment: This is how you would change the name for any activity.  This works for the launcher, and others.

Comment: This would mess up the Toolbar title - if you are using Material style Toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, The above works for fresh copies being installed on your phone. If the old copy is copied over sometimes the change in name doesn't work. Uninstall previous version, with previous name if the name isn't updated.