# Change App name on Homescreen and Keeping the app shortcut on the home screen with full Application Name?

Tags: android-layout, android-manifest, android

My application Name is big and app name truncated on Home Screen.
Is there any way to refer the Full name of application ?
Currently the Application name refers from android:label="@string/app_name"

Eg. An application with the title "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" will be titled "abcdefghi.." on Home Screen.
so Keeping the app shortcut on the home screen with Full name.

Comment: @jprofitt: by mistake you have posted the link of this question itself

Comment: @MehulJoisar Oops! Guess that's what happens when you try to SO late at night! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062568/android-change-app-name-in-home-screen?rq=1 is the one I was after.

Answer (score -1):

Just an FYI, you can optionally do it from the XML.

In the AndroidManifest.xml, you can set it with

```
android:label="My Activity Title"
```

Or

```
android:label="@strings/my_activity_label"

Example:

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/splash_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: @AnandMakwana Why are you talking about activity title?  This post asks about app name on home screen.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Android manifest.xml , where you had declare your activity
there you can change the app_name..

mention in this manner:-

```
   <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="HomeScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: it will work.
i am damm sure....
can u share your manifest and home screen activity....